# automatically populate the value of first text box into second (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I need to automatically populate second textbox once the first textbox is populated by user using angularjs. Both of them have their own ng-model so I can not change ng-model. Is there a way I can just copy the value from first textbox to second by keeping ng-model different?

Comment: put your working code !

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, you need to build the logic to assign model1 value to model2 whenever there is a change in model1

Your html part :

```
<input ng-model='model1" ng-change="update2()">
<input ng-model='model2" >
```

And somewhere in the relevant controller,

```
$scope.update2 = function(){
    $scope.model2 = $scope.model1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but after I populate the second textbox, user should again be able to change the value in second textbox. And that updated value should be saved.

Comment: This method allows 2nd value to be changed and saved in model2, however it does not update the first value back as I have not added a 'ng-change' directive to the 2nd input.

Comment: Your code given a error. the model1 and model2 is undefined :( . please use ` $scope.model1`

Comment: Below answer using $watch does copies the value from first textbox to second, but it only saves the first value even when i modify the value of second text box. Is there a way to copy the value and also be able to modify it?

Comment: you can use the ng-submit tag and specify the function `<form ng-submit="process()">` , this function can send the model values instead of the html values

Comment: ng-submit does not work with button control. And i can not use <form ng-submit="process()"> because I have more than 1 button that calls different methods. Is there any other way to pass model values instead of html values?

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor changes to your `$scope` using the `$watch` function. This is a more appropriate way for binding changes in Angular. try below snippet:

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch('first',function(){
    $scope.second = $scope.first;

  });
```

HTML:

```
<input ng-model='first'>
<input ng-model='second' >
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer. It does copy the value of first textbox into second one, but when i modify the value of second textbox and save it. only the first value gets save in both textbox. I want user to be able to modify the value and save the changes.